# How to make navigation a <select> list without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I have tried several solution for this, but none of them worked.
I managed to make the nav list into `<select><option>` list, but without only with names of the pages, without any indication of their URL

Any ideas how can I make a fully functional select list navigation without an external plugin?

(The ideal solution would be the pages URLs would appear as a `value` in the `option` so I can use JavaScript for page navigation)

Comment: Could you provide some more details on what you're looking for? Perhaps an example from elsewhere on the web, or a screenshot? Are you looking for something like this: [link](http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/) ?

Comment: @SpencerHoffman yes exactly! What I've been manage to achieve so far is a list of the custom menu items without any indication of their URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a custom script loader, add something like this to your theme's functions.php:

```
function addScripts() {

    if ( !is_admin() ) { 

        wp_register_script('navScript', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/navScript.js")); 

        wp_enqueue_script('navScript');

}
}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'addScripts');
```

In your WordPress dashboard, go to Appearance->My Custom Widgets, create a new widget (give it a name, select HTML as the type), and add your version of this (leaving out the div, as you can contain/style to your liking):

```
<form>

    <select id="superNav">
        <option value="">Choose a destination...</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</option>
        <option value="http://www.amazon.com/">AMAZON</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Then, under Appearance->Widgets, add your new custom widget to wherever you'd like it to go.

in navScript.js (in the appropriate template JS directory, as indicated above), you can add the code something like the code that follows. I'm doing this with jQuery, but it's easily reworked for plain JavaScript using addEventListener():

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#superNav').change(function() {

        var curUrl = $("option:selected", this).val();

        if (curUrl) {

            window.open(curUrl, '_top')

        }

    });
```

Comment: did you see the question was about Wordpress?

Comment: Also it is considered bad practice using inline Javascript like that, you should use event binding instead

Comment: I'm sorry. Based on your previous statement "yes exactly!", you led me to believe that was all you needed. I'm well aware of the best practices and will be happy to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `get_pages( $args )` function to get the list of pages and their respective links.  Then using the jQuery listed by @Spencer Hoffman should get you what I believe you are looking for.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Displaying_pages_in_dropdown_list

That example should be the perfect example to go by (besides the inline javascript).